# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Timestamp, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(***)]

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, mappingexception

Using hibernate.. I am learning the technology at the moment.. Not sure where I m wrong...Pls guide on this..

I see the above error when trying to map a column from db of type - TIMESTAMP() to Pojo variable... 
I tried changing the variable type to Date...Calendar...Timestamp.. Nothing works here... 
The issue is seems to be with the mapping for the column... Any help on this is much appreciated...

**My pojo class:**

```
public class Pojo_****
{ ......... 
private Date C_TimeStamp; 
private Date L_TimeStamp;
}
```

**My DB table:**

```
Table_****
    ..........
    C_TimeStamp TIMESTAMP(6)
    L_TimeStamp TIMESTAMP(6)
```

**My configuration xml:**

```
 Pojo_****.hbm.xml
        ......
        <property name="C_TimeStamp" column="C_TimeStamp" />
        <property name="L_TimeStamp" column="L_TimeStamp" />
```

**Error Logs:**

```
In Main method of MainApp...
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2 cr4
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource: Pojo_****.hbm.xml
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: Pojo_****-> Table_****
Mar 9, 2016 2:48:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Timestamp, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(L_TimeStamp)]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at tutorialspoint.example.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:29)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Timestamp, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(L_TimeStamp)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:410)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1026)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1211)
    at tutorialspoint.example.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to fill the DateTime to the Variable. I Faced Same Problem in Project Got Resolved by this.

```
  Pojo_Class obj_Pojo = new Pojo();

try {
            //Or Pass any Date Object.
        obj_Pojo.setC_TimeStamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse(String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()))); 

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        v_objBorrower.setCreationDate(new Date());
    }
```

Note: Change your database column as `DateTime`. This might help you if any configuration issue is not there.

Comment: I have tried commenting out printing these fields from my main method... and used the other variables of type - string/int... as well from the pojo class/ **** hbm.xml file... Yet the issue exists...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the type="timestamp" in your .hbm.xml file, like this?

```
<property name="C_TimeStamp" column="C_TimeStamp" type="timestamp" />
<property name="L_TimeStamp" column="L_TimeStamp" type="timestamp" />
```

As far as I know Time isn't considered basic type in xml configuration and should be therefore part of the mapping file.

Comment: Code snippet 1:
<property name="C_TimeStamp" column="C_TimeStamp" type="timestamp" />
<property name="L_TimeStamp" column="L_TimeStamp" type="timestamp" />
<property name="C_UserId" column="C_UserId" type="string" />

Code snippet 2:
<property name="C_TimeStamp" column="C_TimeStamp"  />
<property name="L_TimeStamp" column="L_TimeStamp" />
<property name="C_UserId" column="C_UserId" />

Both the above code snippets serves the same purpose.. With/Without the mentioning the type explictly.
I tried execution as per ur suggestion, get the same error again...